# How do I setup a has_many relationship through another model but require uniqueness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 4 models: `Products`, `Vendors`, `Categories`, `CategoryProducts` (join model).

- A vendor has many products.
- A product belongs_to a vendor.
- A product has many categories.
- A vendor has many categories through products.

This is how my models are setup now:

`Vendor.rb`

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :description, :category_ids, :product_ids, :user_id

    has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :categories, :through => :products
    belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User",
        :foreign_key => "user_id"   
end
```

`Product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :vendor_id, :category_ids

    belongs_to :vendor
    has_many :category_products do
           def with_categories
             includes(:category)
           end
    end

    has_many :categories, :through => :category_products

end
```

`Category.rb`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :product_ids, :category_ids
    has_many :category_products do
         def with_products
           includes(:product)
         end
       end

  has_many :products, :through => :category_products

end
```

The join model for `Product & Category`:

`CategoryProduct.rb`

```
class CategoryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :category_id, :purchases_count

    belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

  validates_uniqueness_of :product_id, :scope => :category_id
end
```

When I try to get the categories of a vendor on my command-line, it returns a lot of duplicate results - largely because it is essentially returning the category for each product owned by that vendor.

Here is an example, where `v = Vendor.first`:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > v.products.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."vendor_id" = 10
 => 8 
1.9.3p194 :009 > v.categories.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "category_products" ON "categories"."id" = "category_products"."category_id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "category_products"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "products"."vendor_id" = 10
 => 13 
1.9.3p194 :010 > Category.count
   (7.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories" 
 => 2
```

Some products have multiple categories, that's why there is a discrepancy between `v.products.count` and `v.categories.count`.

How do I get `v.categories.count` to just show me the unique amount of categories (in this case, the max is `2`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is fairly simple. Just use the `uniq` method as follows.

```
v.categories.uniq.count
```

To put it at association level you can use `:uniq => true` option as follows.

```
has_many :categories, :uniq => true
```

Comment: Well...I want to do it at the association level. Can I not do that?

Comment: Perfect. Forgot about that flag :)